# Symfony2 symfony_demo

Tags: php, mysql, apache, symfony, doctrine-orm

I was block here. When I want to log onto the app_dev.php file I have this message

> Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem.

My instalation:

> Ubuntu Mate 15.04
>
> apache2, php5, libapache2-mod-php5, mysql-server, php5-mysql, php-apc,
>   php-intl and mysqlite install.

I have give the permission to the folder `/var/www/html` and `/etc/php5` like chmod. And edit php.ini onto the `/etc/php5/cli` and `/etc/php5/apache2` and added the `date.timezone = Europe/Paris` However, the message error as onto the check.php .

When I want to see the Homepage I have this in red :

> Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: "An
>   exception occured in driver: could not find driver" at
>   /var/www/html/symfony_demo/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractSQLiteDriver.php
>   line 85

But, I have slqite installed.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: In command prompt check by `php -m` do yo have sqlite there?

Comment: Onto the list they have : mysql and mysqli . mysqli is sqlitle? Bun not sqlite in the list

Comment: corrected spellings along with some sentence structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below :

```
 sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
 sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Comment: Thx you so much! i have wrong install of sqlite. I have resolved my problem. but i have do the second command "sudo service apache2 restart"